# Ask the orthonormal design where $p=n$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics

I am reading a textbook, which says:

> It is instructive to consider the orthonormal design where $p=n$ and
> the design matrix satisfies $n^{-1} \mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X} =I_{ p \times p}$.

The background is about regression and LASSO.

I don't understand above. But I know if some matrix X is orthonormal, then $X^T X=I$. I don't know where $n^{-1}$ come from.

p is the number of variables, n is the number of observations.

The textbook I mention is Statistics for High-Dimensional Data Methods, Theory and Applications

Comment: What are $ p$ and $n?$ What is the book?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews p is the number of variables, n is the number of observations. Statistics for High-Dimensional Data
Methods, Theory and Applications

Comment: Put it in the question. A reader should not need to read the comments to know the question.

Comment: Orthonormal design means that the empirical covariance matrix is the identity, hence the $n^{-1}$

Comment: @Andrew Could you tell me why?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you are asking?

Comment: @Andrew Why Orthonormal design means that the empirical covariance matrix is the identity

Comment: Because that's what we mean when we say orthonormal deisgn? Not sure what kind of answer you are looking for

Comment: @Andrew I can understand $X^T X =I$. But I don't know why it is $1/n X^T X =I$

Comment: which part, exactly, to my explanation do you object to? By definition, orthonormal design means the sample covariance matrix is the identity, namely, by definition $n^{-1}X^TX = I_p$.